# Android Service Injection

Tags: android, dagger-2

All my activities use a service, that runs as long as there is anything bound to it. The IBinder provides a bunch of things I use in my activities and I am looking at dagger to see if I can inject them that way. The way the code currently is, is that I bind to the service asynchronously and then once I have the binder I can call and use the things I need from it. Given that this is asynchronous can dagger help me inject these things?